Override standard methods in ext/controller using Adaptation project in SAP WebIDE
We are trying to extend a standard Fiori app via Adaptation project in WebIDE. We are trying to overwrite a function that is in ext/controller/SourceOfSupplyList.controller.js but is even unable to even access the controller (SourceOfSupplyList) in the controller extension file. Is there way to do this?
Below is our code. We could access the utils path and the files inside but we are even unable to access the ext/controller path.
sap.ui.define([
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/ControllerExtension',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/OverrideExecution',
        'ui/s2p/mm/sspreq/manages1/utils/formatter'
    ],
    function (
        ControllerExtension, OverrideExecution, formatter
    ) {
        "use strict";
        return ControllerExtension.extend("customer.zTest.SourceOfSupplyListExtension", {

            metadata: {
                // extension can declare the public methods
                // in general methods that start with "_" are private
                methods: {
                    publicMethod: {
                        public: true /*default*/ ,
                        final: false /*default*/ ,
                        overrideExecution: OverrideExecution.Instead /*default*/
                    },
                }
            },

            override: {
                onInit: function () {
                    alert("onInitOverride");
                    const originalPrototype = Object.assign({}, formatter);
                    formatter.supplierFieldControl = function (oEvent) {

                        // we could overwrite the function in the formatter just fine
                        console.log("supplierFieldControlExtension");

                        // you can still call the original method too
                        originalPrototype.supplierFieldControl.apply(this, arguments);
                    };
                    console.log(ui/s2p/mm/sspreq/manages1/ext/controller/SourceOfSupplyList); //unable to access ext/controller
                    debugger;
                }

            }
        });
    });

Below is our original apps folder structure in WebIDE


You should be able to access the methods of the base controller from this.base within the extension code. This is documented in the topic "Controller":

Within the methods of a controller extension, the reserved base member allows access to the public functions of the extended controller. Functionality can be called by using this.base.basePublicMethod().


this.base.basePublicMethod() is returning not a function when I tried it on my code.

@melai basePublicMethod() is just an example from the documentation. See what is available under this.base in your case.

but the methods that are being displayed are not from the controller in ext/controller though.

@melai What is the result of this.base.getMetadata().getName() in your case?

it's actually the 'sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ObjectPage.view.Details'

@melai So you're extending a Fiori elements app. I'd suggest starting from the topic "Extending SAP Fiori Elements-Based Apps", reviewing further subtopics, and comparing what is missing in your scenario.

I'm extending a standard app (which is actually already an extension of the templates...I think they call this break-out apps) via adaptation. Anyway, I was able to access to get the list of methods in the ext/controller/SourceOfSupplyList.controller.js but is still unable to overwrite them..let alone have the app move to my custom code in the controller extension. Any ideas on how this is done?
